# C# novice question about modifying outside variables inside a method

Tags: c#, variables, methods

In the examples below I want to know a good way to make the bottom example function like the top example. I know that scope is the reason the bottom example does not work.

I am interested in doing this so I can tidy up the main body of my programs and eliminate some duplicated code.

```
namespace example_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int test = 5;
            bool trigger = true;
            if (trigger)
            {
                test++;
                trigger = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace example_2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int test = 5;
            bool trigger = true;
            if (trigger)
            {
                mod_test();
            }
        }
        public static void mod_test()
        {
            test++;
            trigger = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using *instance* variables instead of local variables? If you've got a lot of state, that's often best handled by making that the state of objects rather than the state of methods. You *could* use a `ref` parameter to get your example 2 to work, but I suspect that's not really the best approach to your bigger problem.

Comment: I am a novice, I would need example code I can compile and test myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using a data container object is more suitable in this case. For example, in the following example, I wrapped the `int` and `bool` variables into a `TestData`class. This way you don't have to use global variables and still pass around the object reference for any kind of manipulation.

```
namespace example_3
{
    class TestData
    {
        public bool Trigger { get; set; }
        public int Test { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testData = new TestData
            {
                Test = 5,
                Trigger = true
            };

            if (testData.Trigger)
            {
                mod_test(testData);
            }
        }

        public static void mod_test(TestData data)
        {
            data.Test++;
            data.Trigger = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does work, this also seems to be a relatively concise way to accomplish what I want.

Thanks :)

Comment: Although at this stage you might want to consider putting the `mod_test` method (after renaming to be more idiomatic) into `TestData` as an *instance* method. Rather than regarding the class as just a bucket of state, try to consider what operations make sense for it.

Comment: @JonSkeet I cannot agree more. However, this requires the understanding of the context.

Comment: @HossainMuctadir: Sure, but I think it's at least steering the OP in that direction.

Comment: In general I was just looking for a way to move massive blocks of main app code to an isolated location while giving that functionality a human readable name.

In most cases I am using traditional methods/functions but from time to time I need a method/function to also change the state of certain external variables, this would let me do this.

I am 2 weeks in on C# after not coding for 20 years, I know I have a lot to learn still and C# is a bit different than what I used long ago.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare the properties outside of the methods, but still in the class :

```
class Program
{
    // both of them are accessible within the class scope, but not outside
    static int test = 5;
    static bool trigger = true;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (trigger)
        {
            mod_test();
        }
    }

    public static void mod_test()
    {
        test++;
        trigger = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively he could pass the variables in to the child functions, but I think this is a much better approach to this example

Comment: @Gerrit indeed, but `ref` will be needed. And it could be painful if they are needed in more and more methods

Comment: This exchanges one problem for another though. I want to maintain my existing functionality while gaining the ability to modify these variables in a method.

Comment: @nosirrahx well, you can

Comment: Ahh I see, I must have misstyped something before.

Comment: @nosirrahx did you forget to use the `static` keyword ?